# How to see the failure line at the code using Testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

i have just started using testng.

till now i used junit , double click at the junit tab -> failed message , brings me to the failed line in the code.

However, using testng , double click at the testng tab -> fail message , brings me to the main failed method in the code , and i want to see the specific line inside the method.
how can i perform this?

Comment: What tool is invoking the test cases?

Comment: i am not sure i understand , 
i use eclipse , java project , testng class ,
i run the test using TestngTest.

Answer (score 0):

Look in file \target\surefire-reports\TestSuite.txt